# Deploy a python3.4-based Django project on Centos 6.5 with mod_wsgi: doable?

Tags: django, apache, python-3.x, mod-wsgi, centos6

I have a project that works very nicely using the dev web server but I'm running into tons of problems getting it to play nice on an old-ish centos box with the system apache (ie installed via yum.)  I uninstalled the yum-based wsgi (because it was assuredly compiled against the system python 2.x) and am trying to use the one that got install via `pip install mod-wsgi`.  (where pip is the python3 pip).

Before I get into the details, I want to just ask the internet -- is this even possible / advisable?  Should I uninstall apache and try to build a new version from source?  Should I be using a virtual-env?  Pyenv or Virtualenv?  If so, should mod-wsgi be installed in the project's venv or in "system" location of python3 (/usr/local/).

Seems like other poor souls have [cried out silently](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27606529/config-mod-wsgi-and-python-django-on-centos-6-5-fail) in the dark about the same mix (old centos box, shiny new python version.)

I've read extensively through many online docs, like [How to deploy with WSGI](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/howto/deployment/wsgi/) and [Deploying Django (Django Book)](http://www.djangobook.com/en/2.0/chapter12.html), but no one seems to address this particular combination.

I wish IT would let me use a Debian based system, seems like that would be easier.

Here is my apache version info:

```
apachectl -V
Server version: Apache/2.2.15 (Unix)
Server built:   Aug 18 2015 02:00:22
Server's Module Magic Number: 20051115:25
Server loaded:  APR 1.3.9, APR-Util 1.3.9
Compiled using: APR 1.3.9, APR-Util 1.3.9
Architecture:   64-bit
Server MPM:     Prefork
  threaded:     no
    forked:     yes (variable process count)
Server compiled with....
 -D APACHE_MPM_DIR="server/mpm/prefork"
 -D APR_HAS_SENDFILE
 -D APR_HAS_MMAP
 -D APR_HAVE_IPV6 (IPv4-mapped addresses enabled)
 -D APR_USE_SYSVSEM_SERIALIZE
 -D APR_USE_PTHREAD_SERIALIZE
 -D SINGLE_LISTEN_UNSERIALIZED_ACCEPT
 -D APR_HAS_OTHER_CHILD
 -D AP_HAVE_RELIABLE_PIPED_LOGS
 -D DYNAMIC_MODULE_LIMIT=128
 -D HTTPD_ROOT="/etc/httpd"
 -D SUEXEC_BIN="/usr/sbin/suexec"
 -D DEFAULT_PIDLOG="run/httpd.pid"
 -D DEFAULT_SCOREBOARD="logs/apache_runtime_status"
 -D DEFAULT_LOCKFILE="logs/accept.lock"
 -D DEFAULT_ERRORLOG="logs/error_log"
 -D AP_TYPES_CONFIG_FILE="conf/mime.types"
 -D SERVER_CONFIG_FILE="conf/httpd.conf"
```

Here's a few snips of my httpd.conf file:

```
LoadModule wsgi_module /opt/deeplogic-django/venv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/mod_wsgi/server/mod_wsgi-py34.cpython-34m.so
# lines omitted....
WSGIScriptAlias / /opt/myproject/myapp/wsgi.py
WSGIPythonPath /opt/myproject:/opt/myproject/venv/lib/python3.4/site-packages                           
WSGIPythonHome /opt/myproject/venv/bin
<Directory /opt/myproject/myapp>
<Files wsgi.py>
       Order deny,allow
       Allow from all
</Files>
</Directory>
```

And here is the latest error I am encountering when I try to start apache:

```
Fatal Python error: Py_Initialize: Unable to get the locale encoding
ImportError: No module named 'encodings'
[Thu Sep 17 11:51:47 2015] [notice] child pid 1393 exit signal Aborted (6)
```

Grateful for any pointers, advice, wisdom.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've had success with Centos 6.5 with Apache and Python 3.x (it's because its at work). Here's the set up I am using (I stick with Python 3.3.x and Python 3.4 had issues with pyodbc).

First, install EPEL...

```
yum -y -q install http://dl.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/6/x86_64/epel-release-6-8.noarch.rpm
rpm --import /etc/pki/rpm-gpg/RPM-GPG-KEY-EPEL-6
```

Then Apache...

```
yum -y -q install httpd mod_ssl httpd-devel
```

Then for Python (including some very commonly used pre-reqs):

```
yum -y -q groupinstall development
yum -y -q install zlib2-devel openssl-devel sqlite-devel bzip2-devel python-devel openssl-devel openssl-perl libjpeg-turbo libjpeg-turbo-devel zlib-devel giflib ncurses-devel gdbm-devel xz-devel tkinter readline-devel tk tk-devel kernel-headers glibc libpng gcc-c++
```

Install Python 3.3.5 (you can probably use a more current version):

```
wget 'http://www.python.org/ftp/python/3.3.5/Python-3.3.5.tgz'
tar -xzf 'Python-3.3.5.tgz'
cd ./Python-3.3.5
CXX=g++ ./configure --enable-shared --quiet
make
make altinstall
ln -s /usr/local/bin/python3.3 /usr/bin/python3.3
echo "/usr/local/lib/python3.3" > /etc/ld.so.conf.d/python33.conf
echo "/usr/local/lib" >> /etc/ld.so.conf.d/python33.conf
```

Make and compile mod_wsgi (again, you can probably use a more current version, or look into MOD WSGI Express!):

```
wget "https://github.com/GrahamDumpleton/mod_wsgi/archive/4.2.8.tar.gz"
tar -xzf '4.2.8.tar.gz'
cd ./mod_wsgi-4.2.8
./configure --with-python=/usr/local/bin/python3.3
make
make install
```

Very obtuse compared to Ubuntu, but there you have it. YMMV, good luck!

Comment: I accept this answer because it provides the high level strategy I was looking for (i.e. just compile mod_wsgi from source, don't bother with python packages by the same name.)  Also the `--with-python` option is critical and saved me time.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I found a very similar post here [(Apache 2.2.15 on CentOS 6.5)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24495348/mod-wsgi-importerror-no-module-named-encodings). I don't mark it as duplicate because I'm not sure if the problem/solution is the same.

Take care.

Answer (score 0):

I myself tried the same few weeks ago, my vps had centos 6.7 and apache 2.2 and my project was developed using python 2.7 and django 1.8.3 
I used to get an error which used to imply that whatever version of python I install inside virtual the mod_wsgi was using default python i.e python 2.6 to compile it and in the python [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/faq/install/) its clearly mentioned that for django 1.8 you need python 2.7 or above.

So whatever you are doing is not advisable!