# gulp python error while npm install

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, gulp, npm-install

I'm trying to run `npm install` for a project, it's showing below error. Anyone have any idea about this? I'm not able to run my project because of this package install error.

[image: console error]

**Updated:**

Above one resolved by **correcting Python path**, getting another error:

[image: new error]

Comment: It might be helpful to edit your question to include the error message in the question text, or even in the title, to make it easier to search for. Searching for your ImportError brings up a few SO questions already that might be helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24495348/mod-wsgi-importerror-no-module-named-encodings http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38132755/importerror-no-module-named-encodings

Comment: thanks @Gyppo, that one is corrected getting another error

Comment: install node-gyp and also install everything it needs on a windows machine. See: [node-gyp installation](https://github.com/nodejs/node-gyp#installation)